# Android make check in or check out button with style

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I need to make a style like following screen shot [image: this]

PLZ NEED HELP !!!!

I have tried using make custom style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttion_inner_icon" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttion_inner_icon" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

But its not as I want

Please help me to make view same as screen shot

Comment: Can you show screenshot of what you get using this?

Comment: i have placed screen shot please verify it

Comment: Pragna, that's what you WANT. I am asking what you currently ACHIEVED using your selectors.

Comment: i have not achieved any thing yet i want to develop like above screen shot.

Comment: plz help me to solve the problem]\

Answer (score 0):

You have setted the same drawable when state_checked = true and state_checked = false.

You must have two differents drawables.

Comment: can you please explain in detailed?

Comment: You must have thow iamges/drawables differents: When is checked and not. But you set the same drawable for two states: @drawable/buttion_inner_icon

You should have some like this:
@drawable/button_checked
@drawable/button_not_checked

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ToggleButton` for this. In your xml file, set the text to an empty string, otherwise it will show 'on' and 'off'.

```
android:textOff=""
android:textOn=""
```

Then you have to add two drawables: one with the handle on the left side (so that 'check in' is visible, this is the unchecked state, name it for example 'check_in_unchecked'), and one with handle on the right side (so that 'check out' is visible, this is the checked state, name it for example 'check_in_checked'). After that, add a selector as background of your ToggleButton:

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_check_in"
```

selector_check_in will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_in_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/check_in_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: @Pragna Please tell us how this is different from what you want, so we can give a better solution.

Comment: i want it like slide button